# Pythonic way to "merge" two lists to a list of tuples

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have two lists

`L1 = [1,2,3]`

and

`L2 = [a,b,c]`

Whats the fastest way to convert this to the list `M = [(1,a),(2,b),(3,c)]`?

I tried `M = [(x,y) for x in L1 for y in L2]` but this gives me all possible combination of elements. Sure I can write a loop to do it, but is there a more pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip).

> This function returns a list of tuples, where the *i*-th tuple contains
>   the *i*-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables. The
>   returned list is truncated in length to the length of the shortest
>   argument sequence.

```
>> zip([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'])
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
```